# Что означает "больно ты скор"?

Tags: значение-слов

Что означает "больно ты скор"?

Comment: Уточните, где вы встретили это выражение. И, простите, у вас русский - родной?

Comment: @Morkovkin Русский не мой родной (я венгр). Это слово я встретил в книге "Инквизитор и нимфа" (Автор: Юлия Зонис): Эрлик покачал головой: – Больно ты скор. Не так-то просто это сделать. Оборотня можно убить лишь серебряным мечом, а меч у лисы.

Comment: ясно. спасибо. Тогда надо бы подробно все объяснить. Но вон вам уже все и рассказали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скор - краткая форма прилагательного скорый. То есть "больно ты скор" = ты слишком быстрый (в рассуждениях, обычно).

Это могут сказать человеку, который дает ответы на вопросы не подумав, принимает решения, делает выводы, дает рекомендации, не взвесив всех обстоятельств.

Еще вариант - выдвигает какие-то требования, не обозначив своих прав или полномочий.

А правда, где вы встретили - и почему затруднения в понимании?

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение. Так как русский не мой родной (я венгр), были сложности с пониманием. Это слово я встретил в книге "Инквизитор и нимфа" (Автор: Юлия Зонис): Эрлик покачал головой: – Больно ты скор. Не так-то просто это сделать. Оборотня можно убить лишь серебряным мечом, а меч у лисы.

Answer (score 0):

> Больно ты скор. Не так-то просто это сделать. Оборотня можно убить
>   лишь серебряным мечом, а меч у лисы

Ну вот здесь все понятно (хотя книги этой я и не читал или забыл).

Собеседник. видимо, предлагает сделать что-то, что предполагает убийство "оборотня". На что герой ему возражает, что тот **поторопился** с предложением.

Иногда с близким смыслом встречается в вариантах, например: 
"уж больно ты на руку скор" - это про человека. который может применить физическое воздействие, в драку полезть - т.е. дает волю рукам, не сдерживается.

Comment: Спасибо, первый раз в этом сообществе (Русский язык), но отклики впечатляет.